# Consequent/nested pattern matches

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

When I send a variable through several pattern matches, what is the naming convention for doing so?

```
val somethingBetweenOriginalAndResult = original match {
  case ...
  case ...
}
val somethingElseBetweenOriginalAndResult = somethingBetweenOriginalAndResult match {
  case ...
  case ...
}
val result = somethingElseBetweenOriginalAndResult match {
  case ...
  case ...
}
```

In fact I only need `original` and `result` every val introduced in between smutches my namespace and requires me to excogitate a new variable name. How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a block and short temporary variable names (just long enough to suggest to someone what you're trying to accomplish--if it's obvious, `x` and company will do fine):

```
val original = ...
val result = {
  val x = original match { ... }
  val y = x match { ... }
  y match { ... }
}
```

You can even omit variable names entirely if you feel like it (though precedence is backwards so you need to add parens or something):

```
val result = {
  ((original match {
    ...
  }) match {
    ...
  }) match {
    ...
  }
}
```

since the result of the previous match is the argument for the next one.

Comment: Thank you for your solutions. I prefer the second form because I do not like variable names that do not make sense in their context.

Comment: @user1625837 - Fair enough.  Having a friendly relationship with transient variables is a good thing too, for those cases where you need to refer to the same thing twice.  Little blocks of code where vals are used like a scratch-pad can be an effective way to simplify a code block without actually splitting it up into methods (and thereby defining an interface, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

If you really don't care about somethingElseBetweenOriginalAndResult maybe you should try to avoid creating it at all. It really depends on the type of original and the cases you consider in your pattern matchings, but there is probably a way to achieve that with one pattern matching. Worst case scenario, why not use that :

```
val result = original match {
  case ...
  case ...
} match {
  case ...
  case ...
} match {
  case ...
  case ...
}
```

I don't like it really but at least you don't create an unnecessary value which you might accidentally refer to later on.